# R: loading package data.table leads to an error

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio

```
library('data.table')
Warning messages:
1: In is.na(secs) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In is.na(secs) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
3: In is.na(secs) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

This is exactly what is happening every time I try to load the package. I installed the latest versions of both `R` and `RStudio` but that did not solve the problem. Given the problem I don't think I can make this reproducible but hoping someone else faced the same issue and have been able to crack it?

I am not sure if this is the problem but - I face this issue on mac OS 10.12. Used to work fine before I updated to MacSierra. Also I tried to run it on the same version of R on windows and it worked just fine.

Comment: What version ? chron=‘2.3.47’ - data.table=‘1.9.6’

Comment: Yes chron 2.3-4.7 and data.table = 1.9.6. I should also mention that I am running this on mac (OS 10.12) I have worked with the package several times in the past and never had this issue though.

Comment: there are no errors there, is the package working normally? did you also reinstall xquartz? I think r core suggests not upgrading the os immediately but too late for that

Comment: I am not sure if it is working properly. It gives the exact same warning when I try - as.data.table(filename). I did install xquartz.. If it is an OS problem then I will just wait for the new upgrades of R. But I am just not sure that it is

Comment: try removing the quotes, they are superfluous in `library(stuff)` and `require(stuff)` , only necessary in `install.packages('stuff')`

Comment: uh no using quotes is safer than not

Comment: removing quotes gives this:          data.table 1.9.6  For help type ?data.table or https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki
The fastest way to learn (by data.table authors): https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-analysis-the-data-table-way

Attaching package: ‘data.table’

The following object is masked _by_ ‘.GlobalEnv’:

    .N

Warning messages:
1: In is.na(secs) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In is.na(secs) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'